# LUA queue implementation

Tags: lua, queue, esp8266

I am trying to implement a simple FIFO queue in Lua, code as follows:

```
dataQ = {}
dataQ.first = 0
dataQ.last = -1
dataQ.data = {}

function insert(q, val)
  q.last = q.last + 1
  q.data[q.last] = val
end

function remove(q)
    if (q.first > q.last) then 
      rval = -1
    else
      print("remove: q.data[q.first]= ", q.data[q.first], "  q.first= ", q.first)
      local rval = q.data[q.first]
      print("remove: rval= ", rval)
      q.data[q.first] = nil        -- to allow garbage collection
      q.first = q.first + 1
      print("remove: q.first= ", q.first)
    end
    return rval
end

insert(dataQ,"a")
insert(dataQ,"b")
insert(dataQ,"c")
for i,v in pairs(dataQ.data) do
    print(i, v)
end
repeat
    local x = remove(dataQ)
    print("list item= ", x)
until (dataQ.first > dataQ.last)
```

When I load the script into the ESP8266 (via ESPlorer) I get the following lua interpreter error:

```
LUA interpreter error detected!
stdin: 1: ')' expected near ']w([[   print("remove: rval= ", rval)]]);
```

However the script runs, and I get the following output:

```
1   b
2   c
0   a
remove: q.data[q.first]=    a     q.first=  0
remove: rval=   nil
remove: q.first=    1
list item=  nil
```

The queue insert function appears to be working as expected, but the queue remove function is not. The first lua print statement in the remove function shows the correct expected value for q.data[q.first], but after the assignment of rval the value is "nil" instead of the expected "a"

I think I am misunderstanding a fundamental lua concept here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: See https://github.com/daurnimator/fifo.lua

Comment: @Amadan it *is* in the source, middle of `remove` function: `print("remove: rval= ", rval)`.

Comment: Works for me using ESPlorer 0.2.0-rc3 and a recent NodeMCU from the `dev` branch. I mean I don't get the "LUA interpreter error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with ESPlorer that I am using to upload code to the ESP8266. Apparently you can't end a line with the ']' character when using esplorer (thx to pjsg on github). The solution is to switch to "turbo" mode (esplorer - settings). This eliminates the Lua error and the code runs as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the output I see with ideone. http://ideone.com/72yQPs

```
1   b
2   c
0   a
remove: q.data[q.first]=    a     q.first=  0
remove: rval=   a
remove: q.first=    1
list item=  nil
remove: q.data[q.first]=    b     q.first=  1
remove: rval=   b
remove: q.first=    2
list item=  nil
remove: q.data[q.first]=    c     q.first=  2
remove: rval=   c
remove: q.first=    3
list item=  nil
```

The assignment to `rval` *is* working, but the return from `remove` isn't because of a scope error , caused by your use of `local`.

```
else
  print("remove: q.data[q.first]= ", q.data[q.first], "  q.first= ", q.first)
  local rval = q.data[q.first]   <<< THIS rval ...
  print("remove: rval= ", rval)
  ....
end
return rval   **<<< ...is not the same variable as THIS rval.**
```

Remove the 'local' keyword, and you get this, which is probably what you were expecting.

```
1   b
2   c
0   a
remove: q.data[q.first]=    a     q.first=  0
remove: rval=   a
remove: q.first=    1
list item=  a
remove: q.data[q.first]=    b     q.first=  1
remove: rval=   b
remove: q.first=    2
list item=  b
remove: q.data[q.first]=    c     q.first=  2
remove: rval=   c
remove: q.first=    3
list item=  c
```

Comment: The two print statements following the "else" are in the same scope. The assignment to rval is not working for some reason. I have also tried without the "local" statement and have tried rval as a global but no difference.

Comment: @Jonathan See my update. I see no problem with the assignment to `rval`.

Comment: I am using Nodemcu on an ESP8266 and think that there may be a problem with the Nodemcu firmware.  When I load the script I get a LUA interpreter error. I removed the "local" statement, but I get the same result (rval is nil). I will check with the Nodemcu gurus...

Comment: Yes, `local` should be removed there.

Answer (score 0):

```
local queue = {}

table.insert(queue,'a')
table.insert(queue,'b')
table.insert(queue,'c')

print(table.remove(queue,1)) -- a
print(table.remove(queue,1)) -- b
print(table.remove(queue,1)) -- c
print(table.remove(queue,1)==nil) -- true
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Though this answer may work, please consider adding more information/descriptions to help other users understand what you mean.